# Can DalekJS call a previous test from another file?

Tags: node.js, testing, include, require, dalekjs

Can DalekJS call or use a previous test (like a login test) and continue once that test has completed? I would like to write my test files as singular tests so that individual people are able to edit only a small portion of it.

I would like to test if a menu item actually links to a page, but call the test that checks if a user can login to the site as the menu item test requires that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 2):

As DalekJS files are just "normal Node.js" files, you can basically do whatever you want ;)

I have some resources on how to keep your tests DRY & modular, go and check out this repository https://github.com/asciidisco/jsdays-workshop/tree/8-dry I made for a workshop. To be more specific, these files in particular:

https://github.com/asciidisco/jsdays-workshop/blob/8-dry/test/dalek/form2.js https://github.com/asciidisco/jsdays-workshop/blob/8-dry/test/dalek/functions/configuration.js https://github.com/asciidisco/jsdays-workshop/blob/8-dry/test/dalek/functions/formHelper.js https://github.com/asciidisco/jsdays-workshop/blob/8-dry/test/dalek/functions/selectors.js